# Is $(2,x,y)$ principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$

Tags: ring-theory

Problem: Prove or disprove $(2,x,y)$ is a principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$.

Attempt: let $(2,x,y)=p$. Then there exist $r,s,t\in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ such that $2=pr$, $x=ps$ and $t=py$.
Since $2=pr$. Thus, $p|2$, for some $m$, $p=2m$. As $x=ps$. Therefore, $x=2ms$, $2|x$, it follows that $x=2n$ for some $n$.
Am I on right track?

Also what happen if we replace $\Bbb Z$ by arbitrary field (e.g. $\Bbb Q$).

Comment: Er, no, $p|2$ so $2=pm$…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(p)=(2,x,y)=I$, then $p|2$, $p|x$ and $p|y$. But $x,y$ are irreducible, so only units and themeslves divide them. It follows that either $p=x=y$ or $p$ is invertible. The only invertible elements in the ring are $1$ and $-1$, so you would get $(p)=(1)=\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, which is not the case. So that ideal is not principal.

If you take a field $K$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$ of characteristic different from 2, you get that $2$ is invertible, so $1\in I$, then $I=K$. If the characteristic is $2$, then $I=(2,x,y)=(0,x,y)=(x,y)$.

Comment: So in each case $(2,x,y)$ is not a principal ideal.

Comment: Yes, that is correct